# edit LDAP Photo attribute, spring-ldap InvalidAttributeValueException 

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap, photo, spring-ldap

I develop an LDAP interface program which can modify person attributes, but when I try to modify the value of the photo attribute with an url string, I have this exception :

> org.springframework.ldap.InvalidAttributeValueException: [LDAP: error code 21 - photo: no validator for syntax 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.23];

I think I must send a JPG photo file to ldap but I don't know how to do it...

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you encounter such an error with a syntax OID, you can submit it to the [OID repository](http://www.oid-info.com/). Here it will give you the following information "Values in this syntax are encoded as if they were octet strings". 
This means that you have to encode your JPG or PNG file in Base64 and set the attribute with this value (in fact an array).

Second, in my understanding, there are 3 attributes to store photo-Data `jpegPhoto`, `Photo` and `thumbnailPhoto`. But for me it's better to store photos on a file system or a database and put in the Directory ans URL or something like that.

You'll find [here a tutorial](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/network/directory/library/v322/ibmjndi/guide.html) to handle them with java.

Comment: link is broken / need permission

Comment: @wmfairuz sorry the initial tutorial no longer exists (2011).

Comment: 'Octet string' does not mean Base-64. Neither RFC 2252 nor the Java tutorial you refer to says so. It means 8-bit bytes.

Comment: Sorry @EJP you do not understand my answer. In other word, I want to say that if you want to put binary datas into into Octet Stings atrtibuts you have to code these datas using Base64. And if you have some knowledge about LDAP you would know that it's the current usage !